error Datalables warning: table id -table-data - Exception Message: SQLSTATE[425221: Column not found:
I have a data table in my laravel project, I need to active orderable in sub_specialties column but this error is show
 Datalables warning: table id -table-data - Exception Message:
SQLSTATE[425221: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
'sub_specialties' in 'order clause' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select
'users" * from "users' where exists (select * from "roles" inner join
"model has roles on roles. id = 'model has roles, role id" where
users 'id' = 'model has roles. model id' and
"model has roles". 'model_type = App\Models User and "roles , id*
in (4)) and users, deleted _at" is null order by sub specialties asc limit 10 offset 0)

It seems like I am encountering an SQL error when trying to order my DataTables in Laravel. The error message indicates that there's no column named sub_specialties in my users table, which is being used in the order by clause of my SQL query. but, the sub_specialties is a column in a different table and there is a relationship between the tables.  So, What should I do to active orderable a column from another table related to Users table???
this is my script for the table :
<script>
    $(function () {
        var table = $("#table-data").DataTable({
            "order": [[0, "desc"]],
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            autoWidth: false,
            ajax: '{{route("admin.doctors.index")}}',
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "extend": 'excel',
                    "text": 'Excel',
                    "titleAttr": 'Excel',
                    className: 'btn-success btn-sm',
                    "action": newexportaction
                },
                {
                    "extend": 'pdf',
                    "text": 'PDF',
                    "titleAttr": 'PDF',
                    className: 'btn-success btn-sm',
                    "action": newexportaction
                },
                {
                    "extend": 'print',
                    "text": 'Print',
                    "titleAttr": 'print',
                    className: 'btn-success btn-sm',
                    "action": newexportaction
                },

            ],
            columns: [
                {data: 'id', name: 'id', class: "hover-success"},
                // {data: 'user_doctor.prefix', name: 'user_doctor.prefix'},
                {
                    data: 'first_name', render: function (data, type, row) {
                            return row.first_name;
                    }, orderable: true, searchable: true
                },
                {
                    data: 'last_name', render: function (data, type, row) {
                            return row.last_name;
                    }, orderable: true, searchable: true
                },
                {data: "email", name: "email"},
                // {data: "phone_number", name: "phone_number"},
                {data: "sub_specialties", render: function (data, type, row) {
                        let text = "";
                        data.forEach((e) => text = '<li>' +e.specialty.name+ '</li>'  );
                        return text;
                    }, orderable: false, searchable: false
                },
                {data: "doctor_booking", render: function (data, type, row) {
                        return data.length;
                    }, orderable: true, searchable: false
                },
                {data: "doctor_booking", render: function (data, type, row) {
                        let text = "";
                        data.forEach((e) => text = e.date  );
                        if ( text == "")
                            text = "Non";
                        return text;
                    }, orderable: false, searchable: false
                },
                {
                    data: 'status', render: function (data, type, row) {

                        let text = '<span class="badge badge-success">Accept</span>';
                        let buttons = '';
                        let user_id = row.id;

                        if (data == "pending"){
                            text = '<span class="badge badge-warning">Pending</span>';
                            //const acceptButton = '<a style="width:25px; padding: 1px; margin: 2px; vertical-align: top;" href="/admin/doctors/change_status/'+ user_id +'/accept" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>';
                            //const rejectButton = '<a style="width:25px; padding: 1px; margin: 2px; vertical-align: top;" href="/admin/doctors/change_status/'+ user_id +'/reject" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>';
                            //buttons = acceptButton + rejectButton;
                        }
                        else if (data == "reject"){
                            text = '<span class="badge badge-danger">Reject</span>';
                            buttons = '';
                        }
                        return '<div style="text-align: center;">' + text + '<br>' + buttons + '</div>';
                    }, orderable: true, searchable: false
                },
                {
                    data: 'created_at', render: function (data, type, row) {

                        return new Date(row.created_at).toDateString();
                    }, orderable: true, searchable: false
                },
                {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
            ],
            initComplete: function () {
                // Button bloacked
                $("table").on("click", "#actionDelete", function () {
                    let url = $(this).data("url");
                    console.log(url);
                    swal(
                        {
                            title: "Are you sure you want to delete this item ?",
                            type: "warning",
                            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                            showCancelButton: true,
                            confirmButtonColor: "#ee0707",
                            confirmButtonText: "Yes",
                            cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
                            closeOnConfirm: false,
                        },
                        function (isConfirm) {
                            if (isConfirm) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: url,
                                    method: "get",
                                    success: function () {
                                        table.ajax.reload(null, false);
                                    }
                                });
                                swal.close();
                            }
                        });
                });
                //End Button bloacked
            }
        });
        App.reloadTable = function () {
            table.ajax.reload();
        }
    });
</script>

and this is the query:
public function getModel(): Builder
{
    return User::query()->role(User::ROLE_DOCTOR)->with(["user_doctor" , 'doctor_booking' , 'sub_specialties.specialty.translation']);
}

User Model:
class User extends Authenticatable

{
use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles , SoftDeletes;
const ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN = "super-admin";
const ROLE_USER = "user";
const ROLE_DOCTOR = "doctor";
const ROLE_SUB_ADMIN = "sub-admin";
const SYSTEM = "system";

const STATUS_ACCEPT = "accept";
const STATUS_PENDING = "pending";
const STATUS_REJECT = "reject";

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array<int, string>
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'first_name_ar',
    'last_name_ar',
    'phone_number',
    'email',
    'password',
    'avatar',
    'email_verified_at',
    'status',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
 *
 * @var array<int, string>
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password',
    'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast.
 *
 * @var array<string, string>
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];

public function userFamilyDefaultAccount(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserFamily::class)->where("is_default_account", "=", 1);
}

public function userFamilies(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserFamily::class);
}

public function subSpecialties(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(SubSpecialty::class, SubSpecialtyDoctor::class, "user_id" , "sub_specialty_id");
}

public function sub_specialties(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(SubSpecialty::class, SubSpecialtyDoctor::class, "user_id" , "sub_specialty_id");
}

public function userDoctor(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserDoctor::class);
}

public function user_doctor(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserDoctor::class);
}

public function userSchedules(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserSchedule::class);
}

public function userTimes(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserTime::class);
}

public function languages() : BelongsToMany{
    return  $this->belongsToMany(Language::class , UserLanguage::class , "user_id" , "language_id");
}

public function doctorBooking() : HasMany{
    return $this->hasMany(Booking::class , "doctor_id");
}

public function doctor_booking() : HasMany{
    return $this->hasMany(Booking::class , "doctor_id");
}

public function doctor_families() : BelongsToMany{
    return $this->belongsToMany(UserFamily::class, Booking::class, "doctor_id" , "user_family_id");

}
public function files() : BelongsTo{
    return $this->hasMany(File::class);
}


public function pendingFiles(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(PendingFile::class, 'user_id');
}
public function bankdetails(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(BankDetail::class, 'user_id');
}

}

The generated SQL is all broken. To receive valuable help, put the code you're using to create your query.

@artrz I update my question to include my script

Also, post your User model along with the involved relations and scopes.

@artrz it is updated also

Does running in tinker: \App\Models\User::query()->role('doctor')->with(["user_doctor" , 'doctor_booking' , 'sub_specialties'])->first()->toArray(); works as expected? (Verify the FQN for your User model)

@artrz No, it doesn't work. the sub_specialties is a column in a different table and there is a relationship between the tables. So, What should I do to active orderable a column from another table related to Users table???

You have a misunderstanding on how relationship work. You should havesubSpecialties or sub_specialties in your model, but no both. If you need to include a column from another table in your results you have to add a join in your query similarly to the way you had in your post before editing the query, and add those columns in your select, e.g. ->select(['users.*', 'joined_table.other_column']) (or traverse your result set get the values from the loaded related models), also when defining your relationships be careful to specify the correct keys.
